# Transmission Compression from .net to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, .net-2.0, compression

I have an win forms App that the users use off line, any they have to sync data using a 3g modem and a cisco VPN, unfortunately the limited band width, poor signal quality and large volume of data transferred is making the sync process unreliable.

is there any way to get .net to compress the SQL commands and then having sql decompress and run before sending the results in a compressed reply to reduce the network traffic?

Comment: There is no built-in transport compression, how much data are you sending/receiving from the db?

Answer (score 0):

To create off-line synchronization i recommend to use Service Broker. You can send data in XML. Inside of xml you can send data compressed by CLR-based procedure on SQL server side to 
Example you can find here:
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/blob_compress.aspx